# error when compile pgrouting in mac osx

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgrouting

I cannot compile the pgrouting. The error message shows like below :

```
[  5%] Built target apsp_warshall
[ 11%] Built target astar
[ 17%] Built target kdijkstra
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/apsp_johnson/src/CMakeFiles/apsp_johnson.dir/apsp_johnson_boost_wrapper.cpp.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks'
make[2]: *** [src/apsp_johnson/src/CMakeFiles/apsp_johnson.dir/apsp_johnson_boost_wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/apsp_johnson/src/CMakeFiles/apsp_johnson.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can some guide me how to solve this. I'm using OSX Mavericks. Any info would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the Makefile uses some gcc-specific cflags. OS X uses LLVM's clang, not gcc. You'll probably need to modify it to not set that flag. Report this issue on the pgrouting mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

I found that marking the flag below makes compile successful in file src/apsp_johnson/src/CMakeLists.txt :

```
#SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks")
```